# ionic project does not install any plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

There's something wrong with my project that I can't install any more plugins, I'm using ionic with angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPzM8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExM8g.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCmoX.png)

I've tried giving several other commands that I found to try to solve it and so far I haven't been able to

Comment: Can you add some more information on versions? Could be npm/Node/Ionic version problem. Also sharing images, rather than code is highly discouraged: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in the error, you have dependency conflict. you have to either upgrade your packages with `npm update` or in this case where the package is angular `ng update`, or removing some packages that cause the conflict, or ignore it and use your command with `--legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: Could you tell me which package/plugin is giving this bunch of error in my project? I can try to delete what is causing the problem for the project to be right

Comment: I tried to download the plugin again using "--legacy-peer-deps" and it seems to have worked (Installing "cordova-plugin-email-composer" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-email-composer to package.json)

Comment: @MatheusPrestes I can't be sure, it says 3 more at the end, just look at the errors you might be able to find them one by one. but understand that you are ignoring the conflict by using legacy peer deps. some plugins might malfunction. the best way is to update plugins, altho it might take some time to resolve updating issues.

Answer (score -1):

try `npm install -f package_name`